# Youtrack API doesn't return populated reporter on tickets

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

I am attempting to query tickets from the API, using:

/issues?fields=idReadable,summary,reporter,created&query=project:$project&$top=100

This results in a list of tickets like:

{"idReadable":"INF-6810","summary":"xxx: Add an SSL cert for this domain into the staging ELB","reporter":{"$type":"User"},"created":1653411002240,"$type":"Issue"}

As you can see, reporter is not populated correctly - it only has a type field. How do I get reporter to be fully populated, with an email or name?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't request any extra attributes for the reporter, you only get the type of the reporter entity (User).

To request attributes of the reporter, list them in brackets, for example: /issues?fields=idReadable,summary,reporter(id,login,email),created